# mysql weird stored data

Tags: mysql

Im having a strange problem with some data that is saved in mysql.
im saving a certain value as text in my db but for some reason some of the text is transformed to this "ï¼¡ï¼´ï¼¥ï¼¬ï¼¯ï¼°ï¼¨ï¼¯ï¼¢ï¼©ï¼¡" kind of symbols.

the code:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['data']);
$id = $_GET["id"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (ID, name, pos,data) VALUES ('$id', '$regionname','$regionps[0]','$data')");
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sim_scanner` (
  `ID` varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `simname` varchar(36) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `simpos` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

the data that is transforming itself to that is a value like this , <151.25,255.54,1254.12>(vector), as the data is generated by a script i don't know the exact value its basicly a characters position once it moves the data is another vector 
thank you for your time

Comment: It looks like a character encoding problem. Can you give us the structure of your table (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)?

Comment: Also wrap a `mysql_real_escape_string` around `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: @Jocelyn i added the table structure

Comment: The result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` always starts with `CREATE TABLE`, (not `ALTER TABLE`) and does not contain `CHANGE` clauses.

Comment: You should also post the data you're trying to insert.

Comment: your mysql character encoding is different to the data character encoding that's why ...for example try use the utf-8_general_ci in DB character set and see if works..

Comment: that seems to fix the problem thank you, wich encoding would i need to use to also allow Chinese letters ? as some characters have a Chinese displayname

Comment: As a note, this example you've given has a gaping [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and is not safe to use in production. I see you've taken care to properly encode `$data` but seem to ignore everything else, even the `$id` variable pulled directly from the query string. This is very bad. Use `mysqli` or PDO and placeholders when making queries to ensure they are properly encoded and do not create serious bugs in your application.

Answer (score 0):

your mysql character encoding is different to the data character encoding that's why ...

```
for example try use the utf-8_general_ci in DB character set..
```

UTF-8 definition for the characters they support, usually UTF8 supports most of the characters

Comment: `latin1` does not guarantee it will handle anything other than "Latin" characters. All bets are off when you put UNICODE data in these types of tables. It may or may not work depending almost purely on chance.